# Find specific matches in an array with regular expressions

Tags: python, arrays, regex

I have ben searching in the forum but no luck to do what I want to achieve with searching for regular expressions in an array. I have tried `findall`, `match`, and filter on `re` library but I cannot achieve what I'm looking for but with `fnmatch` function I did it but I know that fnmatch is not that powerful like `re`.

This is the how the array looks:

```
[0] rule 5 permit sctp source 14.191.156.0 0.0.0.15 destination 201.175.131.64 0.0.0.7
[1] rule 60 permit icmp source 14.191.210.34 0 destination 201.175.137.78 0
[2] rule 61 permit tcp source 14.191.210.34 0 destination 201.175.137.78 0
[3] rule 5000 deny ip
```

Basically, I want to filter the rules that match this regular expression:

```
rule* icmp|sctp|udp|tcp* and that end is "deny ip"
```

1.

```
pattern = re.compile('rule* icmp|sctp|udp|tcp*')
if pattern.search(array)
```

I can do it with fnmatch but I have to do it four times because it does not support the or reg expressions (`|`)

```
if fnmatch(acl[j],'*rule * permit icmp*'):
```

2.

Also, I'd like to filter that if it ends with deny ip to do another action.

```
pattern = re.compile('deny ip$')
```

Comment: your goal is unclear: what does mean your ***that** end is "deny ip"*? what is **that**? How should look the exact final result?

Comment: Hi Roman, I want that it matches this line with deny ip at the end: [3] rule 5000 deny ip

Comment: but that line `rule 5000 deny ip` does not match any of the patterns `icmp|sctp|udp|tcp`

Comment: that's another rule I'd like to match with regex

Comment: Give a set of test cases that can be matched. Which of the examples that you provided should match successfully? See if this helps: https://regex101.com/r/m5OuDw/1

Comment: Thanks, "TheChetan" that link is very helpful and it helps a lot!!!